# Как сделать свободную камеру для просмотра карты во flutter фреймворке flame

Tags: разработка-игр, flutter, dart

Я попробовал обработать нажатия на экран, путем включения миксина PanDetector и перегрузки методов onPanStart, onPanEnd, onPanUpdate, но передвижения являются дерганными и неясно как ограничить передвижения камеры, чтобы она не заходила за границы карты.

Вот код:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flame/camera.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flame/experimental.dart';
import 'package:flame/extensions.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FoodGame extends FlameGame with PanDetector {
  late SpriteAnimation mainAnimation;

  late SpriteAnimationComponent sheese;

  late SpriteComponent background;

  @override
  FutureOr<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    debugMode = true;
    final SpriteSheet spriteSheet = SpriteSheet(
        image: await images.load('cheesesheet.png'), srcSize: Vector2(86, 86));
    mainAnimation = spriteSheet.createAnimation(row: 0, stepTime: .1, to: 4);
    sheese = SpriteAnimationComponent(
        animation: mainAnimation,
        position: Vector2(10, 10),
        size: Vector2.all(86));
    Sprite backgroundSprite = await loadSprite('Map1.png');
    background = SpriteComponent(
        sprite: backgroundSprite,
        size: backgroundSprite.originalSize,
        position: Vector2.all(0));
    add(background);
    add(sheese);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    sheese.position += Vector2(20 * dt, 20 * dt);
  }

  Vector2? prevPos;

  @override
  void onPanEnd(DragEndInfo info) {
    prevPos = null;
    super.onPanEnd(info);
  }

  @override
  void onPanStart(DragStartInfo info) {
    prevPos = info.eventPosition.game;
    super.onPanStart(info);
  }

  @override
  void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateInfo info) {
    super.onPanUpdate(info);
    Vector2 temp =
        oldCamera.position + ((prevPos! - info.eventPosition.game) * 5);
    if (temp.x > background.size.x ||
        temp.y > background.size.y ||
        temp.x < 0 ||
        temp.y < 0) {
      return;
    }
    oldCamera.moveTo(temp);

    prevPos = info.eventPosition.game;
  }
}
```

Также желательно иметь эффект иннерции при резком пролистывании карты.